# How to measure formatting as text?

Tags: powerbi

[image]
I insert a shape and write some text on the shape and based on the condition, the text will display. so I write measure "Display Text = if([Player Selection] = "1","", "Select Player(s) by clicking the player’s name to see their individual or combined strength.")" but this measure is not selected in text condition value tab because of the format is not in the text.

Comment: You can change the format of your measure from the menu on top.

Comment: in the top menu formatting tab format option "text" does not appear. th

Comment: You can use General and try.

Comment: I tried it. it was not working. it needs to be in text format.

Comment: Please try to get some help from here - https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Measure-Value-convert-to-Text/m-p/665262